# Minesweeper Master Google Code Jam Lua

Tags: lua

I've progressed steadily on this issue, however I'm coming acrossed a problem in validating if a spot is clear or not... Perhaps my explanation isn't good so I'll just leave it in code:

```
func.CheckNear = function(field, pos)
    local x, y = pos[1], pos[2];
    local coordinates = {{x + 1, y}, {x - 1, y}, {x, y + 1}, {x, y - 1}}
    for key, array in next, coordinates do
        local field = field[array[2]];
        if field then
            if (field[coordinates[1]]) then
                if field[coordinates[1]] == "*" then
                    coordinates[key] = nil;
                end;
            else
                coordinates[key] = nil;
            end;
        else
            coordinates[key] = nil
        end;
    end;
    return coordinates;
end;
```

Comment: Use `field[array[1]]` instead of `field[coordinates[1]]`

Comment: the issue still occurs, with that tho..

Comment: Give an example of data where this function returns wrong result

Comment: Impossible!

* *
. .
. . that's incorrect.

Comment: Probably, the problem is with another part of code (not shown here)